# Как правильно скомпоновать изображения

Tags: android, imageview

Проблема заключается в следующем: пользователь выбирает изображения из галереи, которые нужно добавить в сообщение, количество изображений зависит только от пользователя, лимит 10. После отправки сообщения, под текстом пытаюсь вывести изображения в таком виде, как это делается в вк или твиттере, но правильно их скомпоновать у меня не удается. В линейном представлении не вариант, так же само как и сеткой. Хочется, чтобы это выглядело как на картинке. То есть, если пользователь прикрепляет 1 изображение, оно показывается полностью, если 2 картинки - они выводятся в две колонки, если 3 картинки - выводятся в две колонки и снизу под ними третья, и так дальше до лимита. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

[image: желаемый результат]

Comment: [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть замечательная библиотека [QuiltView](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary), на основе которой Вы сможете сделать то, что Вас нужно. Быть может, Вам хватит и того функционала, что в нее заложен.